# Different banner on home page

Tags: homepage

How can I have one larger banner on the home page, but a smaller banner on all other pages. 
My home page is actually a page (as opposed to a post).  But I'm thinking the banner is too big (and the newness/cuteness of it is warn off to see it over and over on every page).  http://NealWalters.com

P.S. - Someone with enough points, please add "banner" as a tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like a simple solution, you can use Wordpress Frontpage Banner plugin, it shows a banner or article only on frontpage
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-frontpagebanner/

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<?php
if(is_home()):
?>
<img src="http://NealWalters.com/large-banner.jpg" />
<?php
else:
?>
<img src="http://NealWalters.com/small-banner.jpg" />
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Actually, you need to use is_front_page(). is_home() is for the blog page, not the front / home page.

Comment: I am a programmer and understand PHP, but where would I put this code?

Comment: If you are talking about the logo in the header  usualy its displayed in the theme's header.php file, so edit that file and check for the part that echo's out the logo image and that is where you want to enter your conditional tag.

Comment: Thanks, so anytime I switch themes, I would have to repeat the procedure? I'll check the code this evening.

Comment: Can we expand the sample above using the 3.0.x version of the default twentyten theme - i.e. public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php.  I'm guessing the changes will go somewhere in lines 60-66.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your big banner to media, attach it to your homepage in the media library. On the homepage, go to Featured Image -> Gallery. Make the image your featured image and indicate it should be top center using the radio buttons. It will become the exception to your standard banner on all the other pages.

Comment: There is no such setting on the home page.